# How I can get sessionId for Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can I get sessionId for

```
buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/status/:sessionId
```

I can't find information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Resumable uploads endpoint, one of the headers is the sessionId value that you specify. it's a user provided identifier. could be any string provided it is unique for the object. I can recommend using something like a GUID as your sessionId and then use that for the endpoint you mentioned above.

Comment: Does this mean that the value for sessionId can I assign an arbitrary value?

Comment: The session id has to match the id you've specified when initiating the upload of the object when accessing the described endpoint above. The session id you define when uploading the object can be any string yes, as Jaime said `could be any string provided it is unique for the object`

Comment: Thank you very much. I also want know can I get information, for example it is may be how as status bar, about uploading model, i.e. how much "%" loaded and how operation is execute.

Comment: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/ This will let you know the manifest of the file and here you can see what the percentage of the uploading model.